# Where can i download the Blackberry Q10 Simulator

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

Where can i download the Blackberry Q 10 Simulator,There is no clear link Specfied to download the simulator for Q10.

Only Link I came across for download is

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/bb10allsimversions/

AnyIdea where it can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Q10 OS 10.1 simulator from here: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/

Comment: I think 10.1 is supported for Q 10 and Z10 devices.